# Understrap customize Blog Page - Unclear which page and where to modify

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am new to **Understrap** and I would like to add some margin-top to the blog page that displays all the posts. Unlike other blank wordpress theme starters I have used, I don't yet know the structure in order to add margin top to just the posts page. Between `content.php single.php` and `content-single`, I am a bit lost. If any one can orient me on this, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to modify the index.php page.
I also wanted to add a header to my Resent posts page so I modified the index php as such:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="index-wrapper">
<div class="darkness"></div>
    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container ); ?>" id="content" tabindex="-1">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Do the left sidebar check and opens the primary div -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'global-templates/left-sidebar-check' ); ?>

            <main class="site-main" id="main">
                <h1 class="mb-3">Recent Posts</h1>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

The div with the class darkness was to add some extra margin and color to the top of the page to go behind the transparent header. In the end, this is what I needed.